Find the sum of the series $\frac{1}{1 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 5} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 7} + \frac{1}{4 \cdot 9} + \cdots$
Find the sum of the series
$$\frac{1}{1 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 5} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 7} + \frac{1}{4 \cdot 9} + \cdots$$
Please provide an explanation as I'm only a high schooler.

Hint, maybe: partial fractions.

Cf. this question

Thank you all for your references. My question is answered. I'm new here and don't know how to end this.

And many others. See https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%5Ccdot3%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Ccdot5%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%5Ccdot7%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%5Ccdot9%7D%2B%5Ccdots%24&p=1
